# Sticky header of p-table not working with [scrollable] = true in Primeng.?

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am trying to implement both [scrollable]="true" and stick header in p-table of PrimeNg. But sticky header works fine if I won't use the scrollable. If I implement both, scrollable is working but sticky header is not working.

I used the following css from primeng for the sticky header.

```
 :host ::ng-deep .ui-table .ui-table-thead > tr > th {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        top: 69px;
        box-shadow: 1px 3px 6px 0 rgba(32,33,36,0.10);
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 64em) {
        :host ::ng-deep .ui-table .ui-table-thead > tr > th {
            top: 99px;
        }
    }
```

and for scrollable I used the below code, `[scrollable]="true"`

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars1" [scrollabe]="true">
...
 <th *ngFor="let col of columns" >
```

If I remove `[scrollable]="true"` sticky header works fine. How can I make it works both things.?
Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ls1xe1-9mcw3s?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure in the scrollable table is different. so you should give the `sticky` style to this ancestor element instead:

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-table-scrollable-header{
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

[See it live on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ls1xe1-9mcw3s-bauo2r?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

Minimal example to describe the issue:

the below `sticky` header is not working because we added sticky to the wrong element. to fix it we should add the `sticky` to `.header` instead:

```
<div style="height: 1500px; background: #def;">
  <div class="header" style="background: #fed;"><!-- <- instead add sticky to here -->
    <div style="position: sticky;top: 0;">header</div> <!-- <-- not here -->
  </div>
  <div class="body" style="background: blue; height: 1500px;">
    <div>body</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[minimal example buggy version](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/BaKPGxj) | [minimal example fixed version](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/jOqpQxB)

Comment: on latest version this wont work anymore

Answer (score 0):

I also just ran into this problem, after some digging into the cause of it I ended up opening an issue where I give my take on the problem, perhaps they'll eventually make some changes on the way scrollable works https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/11099

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30875765)

Comment: @AlexisPhilip Sorry but I did answer the question, it's a problem with prime ng, thus the github issue. Though someone out there might find a solution eventually, until then we at least know there's a problem and that's all we have. In case github issue changes, I'll include here [my stackoverflow post which won't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70788517/primeng-table-sticky-headers-with-scrollable-true)